# Upload zip file with Parameters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file using `NSURLConnection` using `POST` method. and also I need to send few parameters in Post like username etc. 
I am trying this since morning Please help me guys.

Comment: The best way to get help, is to add the trouble section of code to the question.

Comment: I have tried lot of methods but nothing is working So I am looking for some fresh answer

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024279/how-can-i-upload-file-and-other-parameter-using-nsurlconnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://test.com/upload.aspx";
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"0xLhTaLbOkNdArZ"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

//Reading the file
NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.zip"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"test.zip\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:myData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body]; 

NSError *returnError = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *returnResponse = nil;

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&returnResponse error:&returnError];
```

Try this